How to Open a Web App in an External Window from an Outlook Add-in (Desktop App Issue)
We’re working on an Outlook add-in and need some advice. The issue is about opening our web app in an external browser window from the "Home" button in the Outlook app.
We tried Method window.open(url, "_blank")?.focus(); not working to launch it in an external window, but it only opens the app in the sidebar, which defeats the purpose. This approach worked in web app Outlook, butnot the desktop app!
We implemented Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync, which opens the app but keeps it in a modal dialog within Outlook. This is a work around, not ideal!
Ideally, when clicking the "Home" button in the add-in, the web app should open in a new browser window (outside of Outlook) for both the web and desktop versions of Outlook.
What are we doing wrong?
Appriciate any help!
